# Clarification on String concatenation in java

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, so please go easy on your comments.

```
    String test = "test";
    test.concat("test");
    System.out.println("concatenated string: " +test);
    System.out.println("concatenated test: " +test.concat(test));
```

Why does the first print statement not print testtest, while second one does? This might be a really basic question, but I could not find an answer to it online. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: Great, 3 upvotes, nobody checks for dupes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not assigning the concatenated String to another value (as `concat()` returns the resulting String), so it is lost.

If you want to get the result, you need to do:

```
test = test.concat("test");
```

The second `println()` works, because the resulting concatenated string is returned, captured and used immediately by `System.out.println()`, but is then lost outside of the `println()` as it is not assigned (so if you check `test` after, it still just contains `"test"`).

Here's the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I understand String immutability. Why does it concatenate in the 2nd case? I am not assigning a reference variable in the second print statement either.

Comment: @user2341013: you're returning the result **into the method parameter**. So same thing.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. I did refer to the Oracle docs, and I understand how immutability works. But my question is how does it work in 2nd print statement vs 1st?

Comment: @user2341013 **Again**, in the second, you're passing the String **returned** from the method, the concatenated String.

Comment: @user2341013 I added more info in my answer concerning the second println. Does this clarfiy things? If not, is there something specific you don't understand?

Comment: The Oracle javadoc for concat could be better... it reads: "Concatenates the specified string to the end of this string." *What it should really say is:* "returns a new String that is the result of concatenating the specified String to this String."

Comment: It is clear. May be I need to understand how the println() method works first ;) I appreciate your answer. Thank you for not down voting it, as I don't think my question is a duplicate.

Comment: `println()` just goes through the list of elements, and prints them out. When it reaches the `concat()`, it captures the concatenated string, prints it, then discards it and carries on down the list. Since the String is captures, it prints the concatenated version of the string.

Comment: @user2341013 Also, don't forget to accept my answer :)